# I want to obtain the guest program function name while using QEMU in user-mode

Tags: qemu

The detail of question is below:

I have a simple program which build in x86_64(Actually, I want it to be riscv64 but it seems not have affection):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int a,int b){
    return a+b;
}

int main(){
    int a = 1, b =2;
    int temps = add(1,2);
    return 0;
}
```

Then, using compile tools like gcc or clang to turn it into binary file add.o .

And then I using qemu-x86_64 add.o to emulate it.
I wonder, In emultion process, are there any means to obtain the function name add? For example , when qemu turn the machine codes which corresponding to add function  into TCG IR, can I have some means to know these machine code are belong to add function?
Thanks for any help!